# SQL Server : ORDER BY variable column CASE statement with NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by

I've got a query that can spit out results sorted by a variety of columns, but I need to be able to handle null values in the sorted columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is an example:

```
Table [People]
Columns [Name], [Birthday] (NULLABLE)
```

Query where `@Sort` is an int designating which column to sort on, and `@pageStart` and `@pageEnd` are ints telling the query which results to return. (I am returning only a selection of the rows, so I am using a `[RowNum]` column nested in a CTE. There is also other processing happening, but I'm removing it for simplicity.):

```
;with results as(
SELECT [Name], [Birthday], ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY 
         CASE WHEN @Sort = 0 THEN [Name] END,
         CASE WHEN @Sort = 2 THEN [Birthday] END,
         CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 THEN [Name] END DESC,
         CASE WHEN @Sort = 3 THEN [Birthday] END DESC) AS RowNum
FROM [People]
)
SELECT [Name], [Birthday]
FROM results
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @pageStart AND @pageEnd
--ORDER RowNum
--The last order by doesn't seem to be needed
```

I know that nulls can be handled with a statement such as:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [columnName] is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), [columnName]
```

I'm having a hard time applying that to the query I am working with... any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're mostly there. Instead of a `CASE...WHEN...END` statement you could instead use `ISNULL()`

You'll need to choose relevant values from the same datatype, but for `@Sort = 0` for example you could use

```
CASE WHEN @Sort = 0 THEN ISNULL([Name], '') END,
```

It also looks like you could condense you sequence of `CASE...WHEN...END` statements into one more like

```
CASE @Sort
    WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL([Name], '')
    WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL([Birthday], 0)
...
...
END
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes it a lot cleaner, and the solution works great

Comment: @Dems makes some good points regarding performance, but I guess that really depends on your dataset and server. Afterall performance may be acceptable for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the sort parameter with the null check in the `CASE` expressions:

```
;with results as(
SELECT [Name], [Birthday], ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY 
       CASE WHEN @Sort = 0 AND [Name] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Name],
       CASE WHEN @Sort = 2 AND [Birthday] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Birthday],
       CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 AND [Name] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Name] DESC,
       CASE WHEN @Sort = 3 AND [Birthday] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [Birthday] DESC)As RowNum
FROM [People]
)
SELECT [Name], [Birthday]
FROM results
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @pageStart AND @pageEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is good in terms of code re-use.  Unfortunately it's also poor in terms of optimisability.  *(Is that even a real word?)*

For this *single* query, the optimiser needs to build a *single* execution plan.  It can't, for example, switch between different indexes for the ordering.  Instead it will have to 'manually' re-order the data as your parameters change.

This is especially relevant in paging.  With a suitable index, the optimiser can use a range seek to jump straight to the rows you need.  In the case of your single query, the effect will be to actually process the whole table, ordering appropriately, then jump to the appropriate records.  *(The result of having a single plan to suit all parameters.)*  For any significant amount of data, that is an *extermely* large overhead.

For this reason, it's actually often much more performant to approach this with Dynamic SQL.  This allows each different ordering to have it's own execution plan.  And then each plan case use the index most appropriate to those needs.

Comment: So I actually built the initial version of this (much more complicated) query using Dynamic SQL, but the maintainability of that query was a bit of a headache, so I've subsequently switched to this...

Comment: @brett - I assume, therefore, that this is a much simplified version?  I agree that dynamic sql feels inelegant and has a maintainability overhead, but trying to squeeze all of this into a single query can also have a significant performance overhead.  It's a horrible trade-off.  *[I'm also looking up a link to an article about synamic serach for you.  It has the same characteristics as dynamic sort.]*

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html  *(Link courtesy of @MartinSmith in many other questions)*

Comment: yeah, the actual query is an ugly beast. I'm pulling from a temp table in this query, rather than a table called [Person]. The temp table is built from a SQL Function, and then used later to calculate and return tables listing filter data off of the result set...